# Math symbols displayed incorrectly in LyX

Tags: math-mode, lyx

I've been able to use LyX smoothly until today.

The math symbols in LyX displayed incorrectly starting from today. The problems include subs and sups as well as all the Greek/Latin symbols.

For example, after inputing `\sigma`, I can only see 3/4 on the interface.

The generated `.pdf` file looks good. Besides, after turning `Instant Preview` on in preference, the display is correct. But if I move the cursor to the expression, I can see that the problem remains. I've tried to uninstall LyX and reinstall it again, but the problem is still there.

Could anyone let me know the possible solution?

Comment: There must be a problem with your system fonts (or with how LyX finds/reads them). What OS do you use? Did you do any system update or the like? What LyX version do you use? (please always give your LyX version in your posts)

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Windows 10, and the lyx version is 2.2.3, the newest one. I was running a disk cleanup of disk C while launching lyx. This might be the reason of the problem?

Comment: Perhaps. You could try uninstalling and reinstalling LyX, but I'm not too confident that will fix it. Unfortunately I don't have a better idea. If you do find a solution, please post it back here. I've seen this problem come up occasionally.

Comment: Have tried that, and it doesn't work. Thanks and I'll post the solution if I find it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using LyX in Windows 10, check whether Windows Update has successfully installed all latest updates.

My friend and I experienced the same math display problems as posted above (using LyX on Windows 10), which began in summer 2017. We tried uninstalling and then reinstalling different versions of MikTex/TexLive and LyX, but the math display problems remained (though the math symbols were correct in the compiled pdf files). In the meanwhile, our Mac machines and some other Windows PCs did not suffer such display issues at all. As non-experts, we just suspected that the problem might be related to some machine-dependent issues in the Windows system.

Today we both found that our automatic Windows Update has been failing to properly install updates for some time, the reasons for which we do not know.  After manually force Windows 10 to update to the latest version (version 1709), we found that the math display problems in LyX disappeared.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please explain the relation between the Windows versions and the problem? Otherwise this might be better suited as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This has been [asked before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425061/lyxminus-appearing-in-lyx).  It seems that in debian it's merely the lack of lyx-fonts.

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-lyx
```