# Lyx showing incorrect math symbols in document

Tags: lyx, linux

Ok so this is what the output looks like in the PDF document:

[image]

But this is what the input looks like in Lyx:

[image]

As you can see, the symbols that show up while writing in the Lyx document are completely messed up, the \nabla symbol shows up like a bold N, the minus sign shows up as "lyxminus" in red letters... Like what is going on here? Am I missing a package or something?

I'm using Linux Mint 19 and Lyx 2.3.0.

Comment: There's a suggestion in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425061/lyxminus-appearing-in-lyx

Comment: @HarryK. also if you are motivated, maybe report the bug to whoever is responsible? I guess that a dependency on fonts-lyx needs to be added somewhere?