# "lyxminus" and other symbols appearing in lyx 2.3.2 for windows 10

Tags: lyx

I am currently having issues with how my version of lyx is handling math mode symbols. It is the same issue that is mentioned in this post ["lyxminus" appearing in LyX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425061/lyxminus-appearing-in-lyx) however none of the fixes mentioned in the post work.

This issue started randomly today, with no alteration to lyx on my part.

I have already uninstalled my 2.3.1 version to get the up to date version (2.3.2) from the lyx home page however this has not fixed my issue. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

When I got a new Windows 10 computer and installed LyX, I had the same problem.  From searches, I figured that he problem is that Windows/LyX did not install the BaKoMa math fonts when the program was installed.  You need to

1. Download the fonts from here: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/Fonts#fonts-workarea
2. Extract the folder
3. Highlight one or all of the fonts
4. Right-click on the highlighted font(s)
5. Click "Install" (may need Admin access)

Once I ***finally*** figured this out for my machine, everything rendered correctly in the LyX window.

I hope this helps future visitors with the same problem.